# Avoid redundant code for plotting different axes of an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, refactoring

I'm currently using the following code inside a method for plotting a `numpy.array`. One can choose which axis to plot, according to the choice the plot-labels are changed, too. This code looks very redundant to me and I'm wondering if there's a way to make it more compact without(!) impacting the ability to understand it.

```
    if axes==1:    
        py.plot(par.x,np.real(self.psi[ni,:,0,0]),'ro-',
                      par.x,np.imag(self.psi[ni,:,0,0]),'bd-')
        py.xlabel('x')
        py.legend(('$\Re[\psi(i=%d,x,y=0,z=0)]$'%ni,
                            '$\Im[\psi(i=%d,x,y=0,z=0)]$'%ni),loc=0)

    elif axes==2:
        py.plot(par.y,np.real(self.psi[ni,0,:,0]),'ro-',
                      par.y,np.imag(self.psi[ni,0,:,0]),'bd-')
        py.xlabel('y')
        py.legend(('$\Re[\psi(i=%d,x=0,y,z=0)]$'%ni, 
                            '$\Im[\psi(i=%d,x=0,y,z=0)]$'%ni),loc=0)

    elif axes==3:
        py.plot(par.z,np.real(self.psi[ni,0,0,:]),'ro-',
                      par.z,np.imag(self.psi[ni,0,0,:]),'bd-')
        py.xlabel('z')
        py.legend(('$\Re[\psi(i=%d,x=0,y=0,z)]$'%ni, 
                            '$\Im[\psi(i=%d,x=0,y=0,z)]$'%ni),loc=0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite `self.psi[ni,:,0,0]` as:

```
idx = [ni, 0, 0, 0]
idx[axes] = slice(None)
self.psi[tuple(idx)]
```

or even as:

```
idx = (ni,) + (0,)*(axes-1) + (slice(None),) + (0,)*(3-axes)
sel.psi[idx]
```

For the labeling of the x axis, I think `'xyz'[axes-1]` would work, and you can reuse this idea to rewrite e.g. `par.x` as `geattr(par, 'xyz'[axes-1])`

Comment: I don't think the second line needs `axes+1`, since `ni` is in axis 0.  Should be `idx[axes] = slice(None)`.  Likewise, `idx = (ni,) + (0,)*(axes-1) + (slice(None),) + (0,)*(3-axes)` and `'xyz'[axes-1]`  I guess you could just start with `axes-=1` :P

Answer (score 1):

You can have a dictionary of the values to supply to plot, xlabel, range and legend such as:

```
Axdict = {
    1:(par.x, 'x', 'ni,:,0,0', '(i=%d,x,y=0,z=0)'), 
    2:(par.y, 'y', 'ni,0,:,0', '(i=%d,x=0,y,z=0)'),
    3:(par.z, 'z', 'ni,0,0,:', '(i=%d,x=0,y=0,z)'),
}
p, lx, rs, l = Axdict.get(axes)   # Look up your subst
cdata = eval("self.psi[%s]" % rs) # Get the data you need
py.plot(p,np.real(cdata),'ro-',
        p,np.imag(cdata),'bd-')   # Plot it
py.xlabel(lx)                     # Use the label
lr = '$\Re[\psi()]$' % l          # Real Legend
li = '$\Im[\psi()]$' % l          # Imaginary Legend
py.legend((lr%ni, li%ni),loc=0)   # Add the legend
```

Comment: Using `getattr` you could eliminate the first column.